# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, garbage-collection

I have a Java program which continuously checks for updates to a MySQL table.

When it returns a ResultSet with data, it sends out an alert.

This code is currently running for about 2 hours, then it errors with:

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackField(MysqlIO.java:718)***

```
Connection conn = DBClass.getConnection();

    while(true) {

    try {

        ResultSet rs = DBClass.getLatestArbs(conn);

        while(rs.next()) {

            String runnerName = rs.getString("RUNNER_NAME");        

            if(!sentAlerts.contains(runnerName)) {

                sendText(phoneNo, runnerName);
                sentAlerts.add(runnerName);

            }
        }

        rs.close();

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**DBClass.getLatestArbs(conn):**

```
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE RUNNER_SCORE > 10 AND UPDATE_TSTAMP > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";

        // create the java statement
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        // execute the query, and get a java resultset
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return rs;
```

Comment: Are you seeing stack traces throughout your logs? It's a bit of a guess, but I'm wondering if there are cases where rs.close() isn't being called as a result of an exception, and over time its adding up.

Comment: Don't see where `Statement st` is closed.

Comment: @tsolakp that could well be the problem! I was checking through to make sure everything was closed and missed the Statement. Will make that code change and see if that improves things. Thank you.

Comment: The SQL is static, so you don't actually need to create the `Statement` every time. Just do it once outside the loop.